Как отключить возможность нажатия одним пальцем в AccessibilityService при разработке своего экранного диктора для android

Я разрабатываю свою программу чтения с экрана.
Моя цель добиться схожего результата как у TalkBack или Orca но я немогу понять как реализовать управление жестами и просто двойное нажатие одним пальцем.
Я почти добился результата с помощью performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK) но результат немного не тот что мне нужен ( Мне нужно сразу отменить клик а не тогда когда пользователь уже активировал Switch и т.д. )
Может кто-то мастер в этом:)
P.S. Я уже спрашивал у Chat gpt, он не смог помочь, он даже вечный автокликер создал и я не мог ничего сделать пришлось наблюдать как баг ( код воставшей программы ) нажимает повсюду:)


я просто установил флаг FLAG_REQUEST_TOUCH_EXPLORATION_MODE, и тем самым заблокировал нажатие одним пальцем.
